# Simplifying Dr.Racket alien code

Tags: racket

I am using Dr.Racket, *Intermediate Student with Lambda*. I was wondering if there was any way I can simplify this code using any sort of method like lambda, abstraction, map, filter, etc.

```
 ; alien-at-edge?: alien --> boolean
(define (alien-at-edge? an-alien)
(or (alien-at-right-edge? an-alien)
(alien-at-left-edge? an-alien)))    

; any-alien-at-edge?: loa --> boolean 
(define (any-alien-at-edge? a-loa) 
(cond [(empty? a-loa) false] 
[else (or (alien-at-edge? (first a-loa)) 
      (any-alien-at-edge? (rest a-loa)))])) 

;alien-at-left-edge?: alien --> boolean
(define (alien-at-left-edge? an-alien)
 (<= (- (posn-x an-alien) ALIEN-DELTA-X) alien-half))  

;alien-at-right-edge?: alien --> boolean
(define (alien-at-right-edge? an-alien)
(>= (+ (posn-x an-alien) ALIEN-DELTA-X) (- WIDTH alien-half))) 

;any-alien-at-right-edge?: loa --> boolean 
(define (any-alien-at-right-edge? a-loa) 
(cond [(empty? a-loa) false] 
[else (or (alien-at-right-edge? (first a-loa)) 
      (any-alien-at-right-edge? (rest a-loa)))])) 

;any-alien-at-left-edge?: loa --> boolean 
(define (any-alien-at-left-edge? a-loa) 
(cond [(empty? a-loa) false] 
[else (or (alien-at-left-edge? (first a-loa)) 
      (any-alien-at-left-edge? (rest a-loa)))]))
```

Comment: In what sort of ways do you think lambda, filter, map, and abstraction might be applied to simplify the code?

Comment: Can you reindent the code?  Also, have you read chapter 16 on "Similarities"?  http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_three.html

Answer (score 2):

```
 ; alien-at-edge?: alien --> boolean
(define (alien-at-edge? an-alien)
(or (alien-at-right-edge? an-alien)
(alien-at-left-edge? an-alien)))
```

Not much to do here but don't forget about indentation to make your code readable.

```
; any-alien-at-edge?: loa --> boolean 
(define (any-alien-at-edge? a-loa) 
(cond [(empty? a-loa) false] 
[else (or (alien-at-edge? (first a-loa)) 
      (any-alien-at-edge? (rest a-loa)))]))
```

This pattern occurs a lot in functional programming: produce a value (a boolean here) by applying a function (`or` here) to your list. You can rewrite your function as:

```
; any-alien-at-edge?: loa --> boolean 
(define (any-alien-at-edge? a-loa) 
  (foldl or false a-loa)
```

You can also use `ormap` if `foldl` is hard to understand.

```
;alien-at-left-edge?: alien --> boolean
(define (alien-at-left-edge? an-alien)
 (<= (- (posn-x an-alien) ALIEN-DELTA-X) alien-half))  

;alien-at-right-edge?: alien --> boolean
(define (alien-at-right-edge? an-alien)
(>= (+ (posn-x an-alien) ALIEN-DELTA-X) (- WIDTH alien-half)))
```

Watch out for indentation and trailing spaces.

```
;any-alien-at-right-edge?: loa --> boolean 
(define (any-alien-at-right-edge? a-loa) 
(cond [(empty? a-loa) false] 
[else (or (alien-at-right-edge? (first a-loa)) 
      (any-alien-at-right-edge? (rest a-loa)))])) 

;any-alien-at-left-edge?: loa --> boolean 
(define (any-alien-at-left-edge? a-loa) 
(cond [(empty? a-loa) false] 
[else (or (alien-at-left-edge? (first a-loa)) 
      (any-alien-at-left-edge? (rest a-loa)))]))
```

Those ones can also be implemented using foldl. Try it out!

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite all your any- functions in one definition like this

```
(define (any predicate? a-loa) 
     (cond [(empty? a-loa) false] 
           [else (or (predicate? (first a-loa)) 
                     (any predicate? (rest a-loa)))]))
```

There is also a [findf](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._findf%29%29) function in standard library